# I am getting a name error in my coding any one know why?

Tags: discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, Reason=None):
    await Member.add_roles(get_role)
    await get_role('751096892867477594')
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} Has been muted')
```

So I am coding a mute command in discord.py and that is the code for it, but when I run the bot and try and mute my test account I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command mute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\sitepackages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\discord bot in python\bot.py", line 85, in mute
    await Member.add_roles(get_role)
NameError: name ‘Member’ is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command. invoke (ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(“ctx.args, “*ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name ‘Member’ is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Member` in line 4 is supposed to be lowercase like you passed it in your parameters. Also to get a role use [`get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) and role ids are supposed to be `int` which you passed as a `str`. The following code will work for you, just change `id` to your muted role's id.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=750678725544247329)
    await member.add_roles(muted_role, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} Has been muted')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors:

- In `Member.add_roles(...)`, `Member` has to be in lower case.
- You need to get the role before adding it to your user.
- The way you use [`get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Guild.get_role) is wrong → The role id must be an integer, not a string / Writing `get_role()` wont work since it's a [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) class method.

Your code should look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_guild_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, Reason=None):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(751096892867477594)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member.mention} Has been muted')
```